# Calling a promise in a test get error 400 in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, promise, contentful

I'm trying to use Contentful, a new JS library for building static websites. I want to use it in Node JS.

I created an app file like this (the name is getContent.js):

```
'use strict';

var contentful = require('contentful')


var client = contentful.createClient({
    space: '****',
    accessToken: '****' 
  });

module.exports = client;

function getEntry() {
  return client.getEntry('******')
  .then(function (entry) {
    // logs the entry metadata
    console.log(entry.sys)

    // logs the field with ID title
    console.log(entry.fields.channelName)
  })
}
```

Then I created a test (getContent.test.js) like this:

```
'use strict';

let chai = require('chai');
let should = chai.should();
var expect = chai.expect;

var rewire = require("rewire");
let getContent = rewire("./getContent.js");

describe('Retreive existing', () => {
  it('it should succeed', (done) => {
    getContent.getEntry({contentName:'****'
    }, undefined, (err, result) => {
      try {
        expect(err).to.not.exist;
        expect(result).to.exist;
        // res.body.sould be equal
        done();
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

but I obtain this error:

> Retreive existing (node:42572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Error: Request failed with status code 400
>       at createError (/Users/ire/Projects/SZDEMUX_GDPR/api/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.node.js:886:15)
>       at settle (/Users/ire/Projects/SZDEMUX_GDPR/api/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.node.js:1049:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/ire/Projects/SZDEMUX_GDPR/api/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.node.js:294:11)
>       at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) (node:42572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3) (node:42572) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Do you know what I'm missing? the promise is ok, I already tested it with a simple *node getContent.js*

Comment: In your code you call `getEntry()` as a promise, but in your test you call `getEntry()` with a callback. Use `getEntry()` as a promise in your test.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I already tried creating a function in the main file and inserting the promise inside, but I still get errors. Can you please show me what's the best way to do it? I'm going crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing few issues with your code:

**1. Invalid Args**

In your test function, in getContent.js, you are passing an argument to the getEntry method (return client.getEntry('******'), whereas you are passing an object in the test (getContent.getEntry({}))

**2. Mixing Promises & Callbacks**

```
it('it should succeed', (done) => {
  getContent.getEntry("****")
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);

      try {
        expect(result).to.exist;
        // res.body.sould be equal
        done();
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      done(error)
    })
});
```

**3. Source of Unhandled Promise rejection is not clear:**

Is it coming from your test function in getContent.js, or, is it coming from your actual test?

Probably, this could also come from,

```
expect(err).to.not.exist;
expect(result).to.exist;
```

Always catch errors in Promises and reject it with proper reason to avoid issues like this.

Could you please update your code and repost it, so that its clear for other users?

Comment: If I knew how to do it, I would do it :D sorry, but I'm new with NodeJS and I'm trying to understand your comment, but it's really hard

Comment: I have updated the code under Point 2. Could you please use the same code in your test and see if you are getting console messages?

Comment: `Retreive existing
{ sys:
   { space: { sys: [Object] },
     id: '3nWKiVDdduwCsiCgwYsiSW',
     type: 'Entry',
     createdAt: '2018-05-03T13:42:01.277Z',
     updatedAt: '2018-05-03T13:42:01.277Z',
     environment: { sys: [Object] },
     revision: 1,
     contentType: { sys: [Object] },
     locale: 'de' },
  fields: { channelName: 'SZ 2' } } undefined
     AssertionError: expected { Object (sys, fields) } to not exist
      at getContent.getEntry.then (getContent.test.js:27:29)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)`

Comment: Updated the section based on your comments.